# Prove that $f'(c ) = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Let $f: (a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function defined on $(a,b)$. Let $c \in (a,b)$ be a local maximum and $f'( c)$ exists. Prove that $f'(c ) = 0$

Sometihng I have thought so far: For some $\delta >0$, any point $x \in (c-\delta, c+\delta)$, we have $f'(c ) = \lim_{x\to c}\frac{f(x ) - f(c )}{x-c}$

According to [Fermat's proposition 6.8](https://books.google.com/books?id=hW_SBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA120&lpg=PA120&dq=fermat's%20proposition%206.8&source=bl&ots=ZAEaYLnYBi&sig=dZIqn_MlobeH5BIt-775brBa6Hg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=7PyTVda0IsmpsAWK3aLoDw&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=fermat's%20proposition%206.8&f=false),

If lim$_{x \to c^-}, f'(c ) \leq 0$.

if lim$_{x\to c^+}, f'(c ) \geq 0$.

Therefore, $f'(c ) =0$... (according to the Intermediate value theorem).

Would that be correct if I do that? Thanks.

Comment: Your statment that $f'(c) = \frac{f(x) - f(c)}{x-c}$ is incorrect.

Comment: You're correct. I would rather say, however, that $f'(c)=0$ because as the limit exists, it is unique.

Comment: And, yes, you need to correct the definition of $f'(c)$.

Comment: You don't need IVT. IVT is only applicable for functions $g$ which is continuous on an interval. It is not given that $f'$ is continuous.

Comment: In the two lines "If lim ... ", you do not say anything about the limits. You have the reformulate these lines.

Answer (score 2):

The key here is that the derivative $f'(c)$ exists. Since as you observe (with the inequalities reversed) $$f'(c) = \lim_{x \to c^+} \frac{f(x) - f(c)}{x-c} \le 0$$ and $$f'(c) = \lim_{x \to c^-} \frac{f(x) - f(c)}{x-c} \ge 0$$ you have $0 \le f'(c) \le 0$.

The first inequality follows from the fact that if $x \in (a,b)$ and $x > c$, then $f(x) \le f(c)$ because $f$ has a maximum at $c$. This means that the fraction $$\frac{f(x) - f(c)}{x-c} \le 0$$ since the numerator is negative (or zero) and the denominator is positive. Since limits preserve non-strict inequality you can let $x \to c^+$ to find $f'(c) \le 0$.

The second inequality is similar, except when $x < c$ the denominator is negative too, so the fraction is positive or zero.

You don't need the intermediate value theorem to conclude that $f'(c) = 0$.

Comment: $f(c)\geq f(x)\Rightarrow f(x)-f(c)\leq 0$ since $c$ is a local maximum, yes?  Would not the direction of the inequalities be reversed then, as $\lim\limits_{x\to c^+}$ implies $x>c$, etc...

Comment: Thanks for noticing and pointing out the error. I corrected it.

Comment: @Jmoravitz Thanks. Now I understand that too.

Comment: This is the Alternative Intermediate Value Theorem: If $a\le x\le b$, and $a=b$, then $x=a$. Furthermore, $x=b$.

Comment: @UmbertoP. I know I understand the concept intuitively, but with all the limits coming from left and right are still causing me confusion to understand why is your first expression $\leq 0$ and the second one $\geq 0$. Would you mind if you illustrate that a bit written. I also understand that $f(c ) \geq f(x)$, since there is a local maxima at point $c$. Thanks.

Comment: @Jellyfish I added a few lines to hopefully clarify.

Comment: @UmbertoP. Thank you so much. Now I understand.